# Setting up remote debugging with PHP and XDebug, Configuration

Tags: php, eclipse, xdebug

I've read a few articles on this, and have become comfortable with using Eclipse PDT and XDebug to debug PHP, with the server running locally.
For a remote server and codebase, where I can make the php setting changes to configure XDebug, I'd like to debug remotely.

I'm concerned about the settings of xdebug.remote_host and _port
  particularly since I'm behind a Comcast router (with a public IP different than my Eclipse computer).  Does this imply I'd need port forwarding to get Eclipse PDT to work as my XDebug client ?

I haven't decided if I want to invest time to go that route, or if it would be wise to use the FireFox add-on, 'easy Xdebug'.  Perhaps it would give me all the functionality I need.

Comment: I also want to know if I need the exact same code-base on my local machine - or is there some way to edit via SSH and then start the debug session ?   I'm curious

Answer (score 1):

i am still getting the hang of this, but this is what you need:

you need to set up your local IP address on the remote server so it know where to connect. you need to have a DMZ or port forwarding to your debug system from your router. also make sure to open the firewall on your remote and local systems for port 9000 (?)

the code you are running needs to be on the remote server.

i am still confused as to how to edit it on the local server with the remote files. since the debugger doesn't want to connect to remote access connections.